# FIFO based Queue implementations?

Tags: java, collections, queue

I need a simple FIFO implemented queue for storing a bunch of ints (I don't mind much if it is generics implementation).

Anything already baked for me in `java.util` or Trove/Guava library?

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Yeah. [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

[LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) being the most trivial concrete implementation.

Comment: Notice that the Javadoc lists all the implementations. Also, the second link above it to `LinkedList`

Comment: `LinkedList` isn't an interface; it's an explicit class.  Alternately, `ArrayDeque` is frequently faster.

Comment: I dont need to resize my queue anytime, the no of elemnts is always constant.

Comment: Are there any differences between ArrayDeque & ArrayQueue ?

Comment: What is your point/question? Either LinkedList or ArrayDeque will work. If you are concerned about performance and you don't have resize issues, use the ArrayDeque.

Comment: There is no such thing as `ArrayQueue`, I believe.

Comment: Hey, I'm using ArrayDeque, but I need a way to modify all its elements(Integers) actually subtracting a value from all.. any better ways to do that ?

Comment: Then maybe a Queue is not the right answer. Either that or you might need to create a wrapper class around Integer and Queue that. That way the instance of the wrapper remains the same but the value it is wrapping can change. `AtomicInteger` would be an example of this.

Comment: Just to add one more pointer here... Refer this to read about an experiment comparing the speed of ArrayDeque and LinkedList and plausible reason for the same .. http://javaqueue2010.blogspot.com/2010/06/performance-comparison-between.html

Comment: This is not actually true: according to the javadoc Queue is not necessarily FIFO: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html. LinkedList can be used as a queue because the order is fixed though.

Answer (score 72):

Here is example code for usage of java's built-in FIFO queue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Integer> myQ = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    myQ.add(1);
    myQ.add(6);
    myQ.add(3);
    System.out.println(myQ);   // 1 6 3
    int first = myQ.poll();    // retrieve and remove the first element
    System.out.println(first); // 1
    System.out.println(myQ);   // 6 3
}
```

Answer (score 15):

`ArrayDeque` is probably the fastest object-based queue in the JDK; Trove has the `TIntQueue` interface, but I don't know where its implementations live.

Comment: For `ArrayDeque` to function as a queue (FIFO) rather than a stack (LIFO), you should use `add` and `remove`. If you use `push` and `pop`, it behaves as a stack. (Strictly speaking, `remove` and `pop` are the same, but since `add/pop` or `push/remove` don't sound good as pairs, we go with `add/remove` and `push/pop`.)

Answer (score 10):

A [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) can be used as a Queue - but you need to use it right. Here is an example code :

```
@Test
public void testQueue() {
    LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(1);
    queue.add(2);
    System.out.println(queue.pop());
    System.out.println(queue.pop());
}
```

Output :

```
1
2
```

**Remember**, if you use [push](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#push-E-) instead of [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add-E-) ( which you will very likely do intuitively ), this will add element at the front of the list, making it behave like a stack.

> So this is a Queue only if used in conjunction with add.

Try this :

```
@Test
public void testQueue() {
    LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.push(1);
    queue.push(2);
    System.out.println(queue.pop());
    System.out.println(queue.pop());
}
```

Output :

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 6):

`Queue` is an interface that extends `Collection` in Java. It has all the functions needed to support `FIFO` architecture.

For concrete implementation you may use `LinkedList`. LinkedList implements `Deque` which in turn implements `Queue`. All of these are a part of `java.util` package.

For details about method with sample example you can refer [FIFO based Queue implementation in Java](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/12/fifo-based-queue-implementation-in-java.html).

PS: Above link goes to my personal blog that has additional details on this.